# How to extend Atom editor with package

Tags: ide, computer-science, atom-editor, extend

I heard the Atom editor allows you to write "packages" to extend it to do new things.

However, I can't find it.

And I don't know how to start it.

Can anybody help me to do this step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find packages to install or write your own packages? In atom, if you go to File > Settings, you'll see a part on the left that says Install. You can click that to install other people's packages, as long as you know their name. You can search for those here:
https://atom.io/packages

As for writing packages, it takes a lot more effort and time. Here's a resource to get you started:
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-write-a-syntax-highlighting-package-for-atom/

I'm not an expert myself, but I hope this helped.

Comment: Yes you should be able to. If you think the answer is correct, feel free to mark this answer as correct so that I can finally start posting images.